# Does Jquery datepicker require img files to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am new to datepicker and jquery ui and trying to understand it. I took the example from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ source and made the following test.html

I was under the impression that the as datepicker is a widget it should work out of box just by providing it the js and the required jquery-ui js and css files.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    </script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input#datetext").datepicker({
              showOn: "both"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <input id="datetext" class="datepicker" type="text"></input>
    <p>Click me too! Lipsum toriumn fsdion fsdfsp fsdfsd</p>
</body>
```

I am getting a bunch of errors about missing png files in my chrome Inspect element something like this...

```
file:///.../images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Where do I get these images from? I can see the date picker in http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ is using some styles from resource folder. 
Can any please help me understand how to make date picker work?

Comment: Those are images from a jQuery UI theme. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/themes/base/images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the jQuery-UI [themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  If I recall correctly, they are configurable, so the exact theme you choose may vary.

It's not specific to the datepicker, but jQuery-UI in general.

You may need to add a reference to add the CSS (to a url like: `jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css`).

Comment: Can I ignore these images? and where do I do it?

Comment: @tintin I do not believe so.  jQuery-UI relies on some resources which are necessary to properly render its widgets.

Comment: How do I include it in the above html page then? @showdev, do I need to copy these bunch of images manually?

Comment: @tintin No, they should be in the package if you download it from here: http://jqueryui.com/ You can use the "[Custom Download](http://jqueryui.com/download/)" to "roll your own".

Comment: @tintin, I believe you just need to add the theme CSS file.  You should not have to copy them manually, I believe they come bundled with jQuery-UI.

Comment: Ok, so if I am getting this correctly, as @showdev suggested, I would style up my theme and then download it, and it would download a css file? which I can include in my webpage? Is this correct?

Comment: @tintin I believe so. I haven't used jQuery-UI in a while, but as I recall, when I downloaded my widgets, the theme came with them.

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker uses images provided by jQuery UI.  In particular, you should find an image file like ui-icons_...png when you download your theme from ThemeRoller.

You can use your own images if you change the styles for background in .ui-widget-header .ui-icon, .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default, etc.